# How to retrieve current month date value

Tags: sql-server

I have written a query to retrieve current month value from start date and end date. and am getting current month as well as next year value also returning

this is my query

```
SELECT 
    PaymentTracker1.*
    , convert(varchar(20),DATEADD(m,N,StartDate),110) AS DueDate
    ,(Numbers.N * MonthlyPay) AS DueAmount
FROM 
    PaymentTracker1 
    INNER JOIN Numbers on DATEDIFF(m,PaymentTracker1.StartDate,PaymentTracker1.EndDate) >= Numbers.N 

    where  datepart(mm,DATEADD(mm,N,StartDate))= datepart(mm,getdate()) and  datepart(yy,DATEADD(y,N,StartDate))= datepart(yy,getdate())
ORDER BY
PaymentTracker1.Name
,Numbers.N
```

I am getting next year month value also,

how to return only current month and year  value

Comment: Will this current month and year value shown in all rows?

Comment: Just as a precaution never post business specific data outside as in the screen shot you provided. Instead try simulating the scenario to some test tables and post that test data, if required.

Comment: which column we should consider to show current month and year value? can you post expected output?

Comment: what does the query have to do with c# and asp.net?